# Java - Memory use, understanding how rendering works

Tags: java, memory, rendering, 2d-games

I have some questions regarding the use of memory in Java.

1st. Lets say that you have one .png file for a button and you use it 10 times. Does it increase the memory useage in the same way, like if you had 10 different .png files, one for each button ?

---

2nd. If you write a string on your code and display it on the screen in your program, does it use the same memory like if you uploaded an image with this string ?

In other words, how exactly the memory is used?  I am making a really simple 2D game with Java and it uses 280MB of RAM, i think that its too much and i would like to hear from a professional programmer some tips on how to reduce memory usage in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you create one ImageIcon and re-use it on several JButtons, then the memory used will be enough for the **one** image plus the trivial memory for the several object references (addresses essentially) that each button uses to reference the one single Icon, and so more buttons using the same Icon will not increase memory use significantly. As for reducing memory footprint overall, do what professionals do -- **profile** your code.

Also, I can't imagine that displaying a String on screen should take considerable memory, but again, the only way to be sure is to profile your program as it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what is best on the 2nd question ? I didnt post code because the question is general for my game. I mean that depending on the answer i might have to change a lot of things in the code, its not 50 lines.

Comment: @Athorivos: I can't imagine that displaying a String on screen should take considerable memory, but again, the only way to be sure is to profile your program as it runs.